# Converting German Time Format to English Format

Tags: time, swift2, ios9

Good morning together,

I have an app with iOS 9 and Swift 2

At the moment, my app is in German language.

My goal is: I will translate it in English.

This works good, but I have a problem with my time format.
At the moment, I use a 24 time format like this:

```
09:00 Uhr
17:00 Uhr
23:00 Uhr
...
```

Is there a quick way to convert this in the English 12h format, like this:

```
09:00 Uhr => 09:00 AM
17:00 Uhr => 05:00 PM
23:00 Uhr => 11:00 PM
...
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What format are you using internally to represent these dates/times?

Comment: internally i use the 24h format - but not as a date/time format. it is only a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) to modify

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let date = formatter.dateFromString(yourString)

formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm AA"
let result = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

You my propably need to get rid of the "Uhr" before (you can replace " Uhr" with "")

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it should do exactly what you want:

```
let date = NSDate()
let dateFormetter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormetter.dateFormat = "h:mm a" 
dateFormetter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
dateFormetter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB")
let timeString = dateFormetter.stringFromDate(date) // 7:34 a.m.
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the other two answers, use `NSDateFormatter`:

```
let dateFormatIn = NSDateFormatter()
let dateFormatOut = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatIn.dateFormat = "HH:mm 'Uhr'"
dateFormatOut.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
dateFormatOut.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")

var str = "07:00 Uhr"

func convertTimeRepresentation(str: String) -> String? {
    if let n = dateFormatIn.dateFromString(str) {
        return dateFormatOut.stringFromDate(n)
    }
    return nil
}

convertTimeRepresentation(str)
```